# How to to subsort array of objects

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsarray, nsdictionary, nssortdescriptor

Consider a simple `NSObject` subclass called `Object` with two properties: `name` and `group`.

I need to produce from an `NSArray` of `Objects`, an `NSArray` of `NSArrays`, each subarray containing objects sorted by `name` and all having the same `group` value. The output array must be sorted by `group`.

What are some concise and efficient ways to do this?

Example:

Input:

```
@[
    @{ @"name" : @"E", @"group" : @"Y" },
    @{ @"name" : @"D", @"group" : @"Z" },
    @{ @"name" : @"B", @"group" : @"Y" },
    @{ @"name" : @"C", @"group" : @"X" },
    @{ @"name" : @"D", @"group" : @"Z" },
    @{ @"name" : @"A", @"group" : @"X" },
    @{ @"name" : @"F", @"group" : @"X" },
    @{ @"name" : @"G", @"group" : @"Y" },
}]
```

Output:

```
@[
    @[
        @{ @"name" : @"A", @"group" : @"X" },
        @{ @"name" : @"C", @"group" : @"X" },
        @{ @"name" : @"F", @"group" : @"X" },
    ],
    @[
        @{ @"name" : @"B", @"group" : @"Y" },
        @{ @"name" : @"E", @"group" : @"Y" },
        @{ @"name" : @"G", @"group" : @"Y" },
    ],
    @[
        @{ @"name" : @"D", @"group" : @"Z" },
    ],
]
```

Comment: Would a dictionary of arrays work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a dictionary of arrays would work...

```
NSMutableDictionary *groupedDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (Object *anObject in originalArray) {
    NSMutableArray *groupArray = [groupedDictionary objectForKey:anObject.group];

    if(groupArray) {
        [groupArray addObject:anObject];
    } else {
        groupArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:anObject];
        [groupedDictionary addObject:groupArray forKey:anObject.group];
    }
}
```

The result is a dictionary of arrays.  The key is the group, the value is the array of objects in that group.

If you still need it as an array, you can actually then turn this dictionary into an array by doing this:

```
NSArray *groupedArrays = [groupedDictionary allValues];
```